# Can I automatically embed pandoc's default templates in my application?

Tags: haskell, pandoc

Pandoc comes with several [default templates](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates), which are distributed with the `pandoc` package. However, if I write an application that uses `pandoc` as a library, those default templates don't get included in the binary. I can still use them on my machine:

```
module Main where
import Text.Pandoc (getDefaultTemplate)

main = getDefaultTemplate Nothing "latex" >>= print
```

This will print the `default.latex` template. However, it's not portable, since it really refers to a file somewhere on my system:

```
$ cd path/to/example/project
$ stack build
$ scp path/to/binary remote:remote/path
$ ssh remote:remote/path/binary
example: Could not find data file /home/Zeta/.stack/snapshots/.../pandoc-1.16.0.2/data/templates/default.latex
```

Since [pandoc's debian package](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/1.16.0.2) does not include those files, it's somehow able to embed them. And indeed, there is a flag `-f embed_data_files`. I've tried to enable it in the local `stack.yaml`:

```
extra-deps: [pandoc-1.16]
flags: 
  pandoc:
    embed_data_files: true
```

But that didn't change anything, the compiled binary still complains about missing data files.

So, is there any way to automatically include pandoc's template files?

Comment: It seems to work on my machine, i.e. if I build pandoc with `emded_data_files` there is no longer a dependence on the data files on disk. But I am not using stack or debian. What precisely did you do (or did stack do) after you changed the flag? Pandoc needs to be rebuilt. Also, is `/home/Zeta/.stack/snapshots/.../pandoc-1.16.0.2/data/templates/default.latex` precisely the path it prints or have you shortened it for readers of your question? Because `/.../` doesn't seem right.. could be pandoc is mangling your path?

Comment: @user2407038: The path is shortened, since `...` contains resolver specific information, which aren't interesting. And yes, I rebuilt pandoc: I removed the snapshot (to test whether it was platform independent), changed the flag, and then rebuilt the application and its dependencies. That being said, I'm actually using Windows and just unixified the paths for better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `pandoc` injects its data files during its build via `hsb2hs`. Somehow that step failed during `stack build` I missed the error message.

Neither `hsb2hs` nor its main dependency `processing-tools` are part of stack's LTS, they're only in the nightly stackage versions. The following additions to `stack.yaml` fixed the problem:

```
# part of stack.yaml:
extra-deps:
- preprocessor-tools-1.0.1
- hsb2hs-0.3.1
- pandoc-1.16

flags:
  pandoc:
    embed_data_files: true
```

For those using Cabal, this is somewhat equal to

```
cabal sandbox init
cabal update
cabal install hsb2hs-0.3.1 && cabal install pandoc-1.16 -f embed_data_files
cabal install --dependencies-only
cabal build
```

Here's how I verified that the templates are actually included:

```
$ stack build
$ grep "usepackage\{hyperref\}" .stack-work/install/*/bin/example -a
\usepackage[$for(geometry)$$geometry$$sep$,$endfor$]{geometry}
$endif$
\usepackage{hyperref}
$if(colorlinks)$
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{color} % color is loaded by hyperref
```

That snippet is part of `default.latex`, so it's really included in the binary.