# Should I run a file as a normal file or with stack exec "my_file"?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Is there any difference of how to run an exe file generated by stack: normally or with "stack exec my_file"? In particular, I'm going to use it as a web application on a server.

Comment: once you complied it you should be able to run it outside the stack env. (I guess) - usually you don't actually want stack/haskell/cabal on your server - you just want to push your binaries there and run them - `stack exec` can be usefull to *find* your executable in it's folder ;)

Comment: Once I compiled a program with all profiling switches on, in `stack exec` it costs a few seconds, when executed normally it requires quite a few minutes. I'm not sure if it's a bug or something.

Comment: It runs your executable in a slightly modified environment: http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#exec

Comment: @Carsten "once you complied it you should be able to run it outside the stack env."*. Unfortunately, that highly depends on your dependencies. For example, [pandoc and gitit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491660/can-i-automatically-embed-pandocs-default-templates-in-my-application) don't bundle their `data-*` files with the library by default, and you end up with missing files everywhere.

Comment: @Zeta but that's no stack issue - it's an issue with those libs - wouldn't you agree that a "web application" should be able to be deployed without stack/GHC/whatever present at the server?

Comment: @Carsten: Yes, it _should be able_. However, if your web application is going to use those libs you're going to have some fun. But yeah, that's no stack issue, that also happens with cabal or manual package management :/.